# How to display locally stored raster tiles with zoom levels in MapServer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mapserver, gdal2tiles, tile-map-service

I am completely new to GIS. I am having trouble showing raster tiles from QGIS on MapServer. My goal is to have zoom level tiles shown as basemap on MapServer, on which then I can display features using polygon and line data etc.

I downloaded QGIS using raster tools like this...

[image: first step]

This is how downloaded directory appears (zoom is up to 4 levels so 4 directories)

[image]

Now the problem is how do I display these JPEGs as a whole map which can be zoomed in and out like this on MapServer

[image]

1. How should I write mapfile for this data?
2. There are hundreds or more images so its not possible to write layer for each data

I am a complete beginner. Can someone explain the procedure step by step?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I deleted my answer (and posted a separate question including the deleted answer, in case it is useful for someone else): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445565/xyz-tiles-generated-with-qgis-not-visible-when-uploading-on-web-server