# XYZ tiles generated with QGIS not visible when uploading on web server

Tags: qgis, leaflet, web-mapping, xyz-tiles

I created a QGIS project and used `Generate XYZ Tiles (Directory)` to export the rendered image as raster tiles. Uploading the folder with its subfolder and raster tiles an FTP-Client to a web server, I can open the site, but get an empty map canvas as you can see on the screenshot. The icons for zooming are there, just the rendered map tiles are missing. How to make the map visible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

You need an index file that refers to your tiles. This can be created automatically when creating an `Output html (Leaflet)` in the dialog window.

See this example here, a quick and dirty topographic map I created for this purpose in QGIS: https://daniel-ursprung.ch/tiles/

### Detailed answer

1. In the `Generate XYZ Tiles (Directory)` dialog window, apart from the `Output directory` you also have the option `Output html (Leaflet)`. Define a path and filename here - advice: use `index.html`. I would recommend to save it in the same directory as the tiles itself (the output directory). If you than open this html file in a webbrowser, the tiles map shows up correctly. If this works locally, you're ready to load it to a server.
2. You have to make a little change in the index.html file as this links to the local folder path where you saved the tiles. On the server, you must refer to the path (URL) where the tiles are saved. So in the output index.html, search for this line where `[local-file-path]` stands for the path where you saved the tiles locally:

   `L.tileLayer('file:///[local-file-path]/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {`

   You can use relative paths: in case you saved the index-file and the output to the same directory, change the above line to this one here:

   `L.tileLayer('./{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {`

   Adapt the path to your needs. You could also use absolute path (URL to the folder) like e.g. for the webmap I created:

   `L.tileLayer('https://daniel-ursprung.ch/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {`
3. When you now load your output directory with the folder structure and content unchanged to a html server with FTP (e.g. using [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)), you can open the URL refering to the folder or the `index.html` file. The map then appears as you know it from other web maps.