# Visualize data for vector tiles in mbtiles format on private web server

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, mbtiles, server, url

### The question

I upoaded a mbtiles file to a private webserver, but can't get the data to visualize in a webbrowser. If I open the file, a download dialog appears. So what is missing is a renderer to create the tiles as webmap.

I am new to creating and serving vector tiles, so I probably miss something very basic. Apart from uploading the mbtiles file to a web server, what else is needed to view this data in a webmap?

### What I tried

I have a vector layer I exported from QGIS with `Write Vector Tiels (MBTiles)`. In the Browser Panel, I can then define a new Vector Tiles connection to the locally stoered mbtiles file to load the data to QGIS. This works well.

I then uploaded the mbtiles file to a personal web server and tried to connect to this, instead of `[local_file_path]\filename.mbtiles` using the URL like `https://[myserver.tld]/filename.mbtiles` This, however, does not work. I get an error message saying "The layer is not a valid layer an can not be added to the map". I can't open the file in a webbrowser, neither. So there seems to be missing something.

### Where I'm stuck

I am a bit confused about the difference how raster and vector tiles work. Creating raster tiles with `Generate XYZ Tiles (Directory)` (see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/445566/88814), a separate html file is generated that brings together the separate tiles and allows to view the tiles directly in a webmap. This is implemented in Leaflet.

So I guess I need some kind of webmap renderer as well. Unfortunately, in the `create vector tiles` tools in QGIS, there is no such option to automatically create a webmap/renderer (the html file created by QGIS).

So how do I implement this?

Comment: "I can't open the file in a webbrowser, neither." sounds like it is a general problem of web server configuration and is probably the main step you need to solve, maybe on general stackoverflow.com.

Comment: The file is accessible and can be downloaded, that is not the problem. The problem is rather a web mapping issue: how to visualize a mbtiles file? It seems it can't be rendered directly by a webbrowser, but needs some intermediary solution. That is what the question is about.

Comment: You wrote "I can't open the file in a webbrowser, neither." which might be unclear then. I thought you meant you got an error. But I guess you meant that the browser gave you a download dialog and not a visualization?

Comment: Some pointers: 1) Either extract your mbtiles into a directory tree of pbf files, or use a server that can handle a mbtiles files and extract its tiles per request 2) choose a renderer like openlayers or maplibre 3) create a style

Comment: @bugmenot123 correct, the browser gives me a download dialog, not a visualization. I created another layer as vector tiles, this time using the QGIS tool `Write Vector Tiles (XYZ)` to get a directory tree of pbf. I upload this to the server and I am able to open it in QGIS, defining a Vector Tiles connection. So basically I guess what I need is what you mentioned, a renderer. I will update the question accordingly. The question more specifically is: what do I need to create e.g. or openlayers (or leaflet, if possible) renderer?